# why overloading with different return type is not supported

Tags: java, types, return, overloading

I have searched and found that overloading with different return type is not possible but I have tried to do it and I did get output.

```java
public class inte {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    
    public double add(int c, int d, int e) {
        return c + d + e;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        inte i = new inte();
        double sum=i.add(1, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

This returned the right output:

> 6.0

Answer (score 3):

Overloading like this is possible, because you changed the parameters. Changing just the return type and nothing else wouldn't work, since the compiler can't decide which one to choose based on the return type alone. However, since the methods have different parameters, the compiler can choose the right method. [More on overloading here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-method-overloading-java/)

Comment: overloading is same method name and different parameter which satisfies my case then why it is said overloading with different return type is not supported can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: You can't overload by changing return type **only**. If you change the number, order or types of the parameters, the function is basically different, so you can change the return type too.

Comment: okay if method are same and parameter are same but return type is different then its not possible to overload but if return type is different and method is same and parameter is different then it is possible to overload right ?